# ¿Por qué no me retorna los múltiplos en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, bucle-for, impresión

¡Hola! El siguiente código solamente me muestra el primer múltiplo de 2 que sería el propio 2, entre 1 y 50, pero no todos los múltiplos comprendidos entre ellos. ¿Por qué ocurre eso?

```
function determinarPares(n1, n2){
    for(i = n1; i <= n2; i++){
        if(i % 2 === 0){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
$("#pResultado").append(determinarPares(1, 50));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `return` debe ir fuera del bucle, y en cada ciclo del bucle necesitas recoger el valor obtenido en una variable que es la que vas a retornar.

```js
function determinarPares(n1, n2){
    let res = "";
    for(i = n1; i <= n2; i++){
        if(i % 2 === 0){
            res += i + " ";
        }
    }
    return res;
}
var resultado = determinarPares(1, 50);
//console.log(resultado);
$("#pResultado").append(resultado);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pResultado"></div>
```